# SignalR & browsers Local Storage Use Case

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, local-storage

Before I take the time to prototype this, I thought I would request some input from others.

I have a list on a web page, when the user goes out of range (cellular, wireless, etc) I need the user to be able to make changes to the data for each list item and have the changes persist locally until the connection is reestablished.

So my thought was to use SignalR and the browsers local storage to achieve this.

SignalR is the connection to send/receive the real time data.

If the connection state is connected, I proceed as normal, submitting the form changes in real time.

If the connection state is disconnected, the local storage is used to store the modified form data until the reconnection with the hub occurs, at which time I post the data to the server for saving.

Can anyone shoot holes in this? Pros/Cons? A better approach?

My stack is JavaScript, HTML5, C# API

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Having used SignalR for ASP.NET Web API i'd certainly recommend it.

Ensure that you have all the requirements met to allow SignalR to connect using "WebSockets" as this is true two way connection and will give the best way of detecting disconnects.

If SignalR is unable to use web sockets then it falls back to mechanisms such as "Server Sent Events", which works fine just not as well as web sockets.

See http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms for info on minimum requirements for web sockets with SignalR.

Comment: serverSentEvents is not polling - the server is pushing data to the client in a streaming fashion

Comment: In testing I noticed serverSentEvents had a form of keep alive, as such assumed the connection method was a form of polling. Adjusted answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR should not be used to submit data and retrieve data from the server, you should only use it when you want the server to notify the client (Browser/Mobile/Desktop) about some event, after receiving the notification you can query the server to get the latest data.

In your case, You can check Ado.Net Data Services which was built specifically for this purpose.

If you want to do it with the browser local storage, then you can always save data to the server and in case there was a connection error, save it to the local storage, and use a single SignalR connection just to know the connection state (Online/Offline), once you get the connection back online, you can post the updates that you stored in the local storage to the server

Comment: Why signalr should not be used to get data from server?

Comment: Because it was not designed to do that and there are other ways to get data from server, the main concern for SignalR is to get notified by the server, using it to get data from the server will eventually result in a design issue

Comment: If you're using signalr and you have to send only small data to server, I see no rease why to use WebAPI in parallel. SignalR was designed for both ways. Or can you show me a link where this is written?

Comment: You can do that, but with time, you will end up sending everything through SignalR, and if you wish to have an API, then SignalR won't be good for it

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like do build this by yourself, maybe PouchDB solves your Problem. You do not need any SignalR or WebAPI stuff.

https://pouchdb.com/